# vue-service-cli build errors with file not specified

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

During the build process (using vue-service-cli buid, via vue ui gui), the following error is displayed but I can't find where the declaration is made for `src/main.ts`. vue: 2.5.21, vue-cli: 3.2.1

```
   ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors1:58:38 PM

   This relative module was not found:

   * ./src/main.ts in multi ./src/main.ts

   ERROR  Build failed with errors.
```

#### web.config.js

`main.ts` is defined in ClientApp

```
       entry: { "main": "./ClientApp/main.ts" },
```

Is vue (or webpack) hard-wired to have a `src` dir?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the webpack entry points beforehand:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.entry('main')
          .clear()
          .add('./ClientApp/main.ts')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  but I get this error now: TypeError: config.entry is not a function. But It was very helpful learning about the vue config option